# Instantly completing the animation queue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I need to stop the animation and instantly complete all pending animations.
`stop` doesn't work:
Lets say I have animation that moves element that is on `0px` by `100px` and I use stop when it moved only `50px`. The result will be an element at `50px`. The result I want is when I interrupt the animation, even if the element is at `50px` it will instantly jump to `100px`.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

[$.fn.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) has the option to clear the queue and to jump to the end.

Just do something like: `$('#foo').stop(true, true);`

Comment: It doesn't work when I have multiple queued animations, it jumps only to the end of the first one and discards the rest.

Comment: Thats because your selector is too specific.  Say there are 3 divs on the page, #div-1, #div-2, #div-3.  #div-1 and #div-2 are in the middle of an animation when you want to stop them so that you can animate #div-3, or whatever.  To stop the queued animations you would do:

$('#div-1, #div-2').stop(true, true);

To stop all animations on the page, you could try:

$('*').stop(true, true);

Answer (score 0):

found this at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/stop-true-true-animation-chains-and-callbacks

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        hardStop: function(){
            return this.each(function(){
                var e = $(this);
                while (e.queue().length){
                    e.stop(false, true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

use it by

```
$("#element").hardStop();
```

If that doesn't work, maybe change your original code to:

```
$("#abc").stop().animate(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify manually the last state, don't be lazy. Im sure you can do it :)

```
$('#foo').stop(true, true);
$('#foo').css({x, '100px'});
```